# Merging all button, text, check buttons change events into a single slot

Tags: qt, qt4

Is there a way to catch all gui events like button clicked, text changed, check box toggled, into the same slot without using the connect() function for every widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your widgets are part of a form and you want to submit the changes to a model (or an SQL database), using a `QDataWidgetMapper` might be more adapted than what you want.

Anyway, these signals, except the button `clicked` signal for non checkable buttons, are declared as the `NOTIFY` signal for the `USER` property (in the [`Q_PROPERTY`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_PROPERTY) declaration).

You can use Qt's meta object system to connect all the widgets from a list:

```
void connectChanged(QWidgetList list, QObject *target, const char *targetSlot) {
    foreach(QWidget *widget, list) {
        const QMetaObject * mo = widget->metaObject();
        QMetaProperty property = mo->userProperty();
        // Skip non user-editable widgets (QLabel, QGraphicsScene...)
        if(!property.isValid() || !property.hasNotifySignal()) {
            qDebug() << "Skipped" << mo->className();
            continue;
        }

        // Non checkable buttons have to be handled separately
        QAbstractButton *button = qobject_cast<QAbstractButton*>(widget);
        if (button && !button->isCheckable()) {
            QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), target, targetSlot);
        } else {
            // QMetaMethod notifySignal() returns the raw signal signature
            // for instance "toggled(bool)", we need the signature that would be
            // returned by the macro SIGNAL: "2toggled(bool)"
            QByteArray signalSignature;
            signalSignature.append(char('0' + QSIGNAL_CODE));
            signalSignature.append(property.notifySignal().signature());

            QObject::connect(widget, signalSignature, target, targetSlot);
        }
    }
}

// connect all child widgets to a slot:
connectChanged(this->findChildren<QWidget*>(), this, SLOT(dataChanged()));
```

PS: This will also connect the `QScrollBar::valueChanged(int)` signals of the `QTextEdit`s to your slot.

Answer (score 0):

`QCoreApplication::notify` is probably what you want.  The documentation for it details some other approaches that may be better.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [code](http://cep.xor.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/dd/d5d/qsignaldumper_8cpp-source.html). It uses undocumented (private) part of Qt QObject system. As I am aware of this hasn't be changed or removed in Qt4. But as it is undocumented/private part it may be gone or changed in some future Qt4 releases or Qt5. It will bassicly notify you about every possible signal emited, So you may do some introspection and check if signal you received is what you need.